# Private chat system - get last message of each chat

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a chat system between 2 users.
I have chat table that looks like that: (Here is the schema:[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d286a))

```
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | message_id | sender_id | receiver_id  | message_text  |       date           |
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |     1      |     20    |      100     |  Hello mate   |  2018-04-29 12:15:33 | 
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |     2      |    100    |      20      |   Hi there    |  2018-04-29 13:20:05 | 
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |     3      |     13    |      44      |   Alright     |  2018-04-29 14:35:15 | 
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |     4      |     20    |      57      |   Hi user 57  |  2018-04-29 16:44:34 | 
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get the rows of the last messages from each chat a user is engaged in, so in the above example, user 20 should get 2 rows: row of message_id 2 (Because he is engaged in a chat with user 100, although he did not send the last message), and row of message_id 4 (because he sent message to user 57)
It's basically like WhatsApp where you always have the first messages of any chat at the top.

The problem is I can only get the last message if the user is the SENDER and not if he is the receiver:

```
 SELECT * FROM chat 
 WHERE message_id IN 
(SELECT MAX(message_id) FROM chat WHERE sender_id=:sender_id 
 GROUP BY receiver_id) ORDER BY date DESC
```

I think I should add another column "chat_id" which would be a number that is identical for each 2 users that are in the same chat (so user 100 and 20 will have same chat_id whether they are the senders or receivers, and users 13 and 44 will have a different in this example),

Or, there is a better option?

Comment: What the expected output based on the example data?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an union between sender and receiver for get a result for both

```
  You could use 
  select * 
  from chat 
  inner join  (
    select max(message_id) max_id, user from (
    select message_id, sender_id as  user
    from chat
    union 
    select message_id, receiver_id 
    from chat) t 
    ) t1 on t1.max_id = chat.message_id
          and chat.sender_id=:sender_id
```

Comment: i assume the chat table will become pretty large i advice @pileup to created these indexes `KEY(message_id, sender_id)` and `KEY(message_id, receiver_id)` for this query

Comment: Raymond I am quite new with SQL, can you explain what do you mean by these 2 keys? You mean 2 separate tables?

Comment: No the KEY are table indexes which speeds up select alot ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html ). @pileup  read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: Thank you Raymond!
@scaisEdge - I edited the example and the fiddle to contain 1 more row that user 20 is engaged in: chat with another user '57', so I should get 2 rows. But in your query I only get 1 row of the last message that "sender_id" sent, and if he receives a message, then it disappears

Answer (score 0):

To handle this efficiently, start with these two queries:

```
select message_id, sender_id as other_id
from messages
where receiver_id = :user
order by message_id desc;

select message_id, receiver_id as other_id
from messages
where sender_id = :user
order by message_id desc;
```

These can each be optimized using two indexes:  `messages(receiver_id, sender_id, message_id)` and `messages(sender_id, receiver_id, message_id)`.

You can `union all` them together and sort or aggregate to get the maximum value:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where m.message_id in (select max(message_id)
                       from ((select message_id, sender_id as other_id
                              from messages
                              where receiver_id = :user
                              order by message_id desc
                              limit 1
                             ) union all   
                             (select message_id, receiver_id as other_id
                              from messages
                              where sender_id = :user
                              order by message_id desc
                              limit 1
                             )
                            ) mm
                      );
```

The subqueries should be able to make use of the indexes (actually, the "other id" is not needed).  The `max()` is then on two rows, and the `in` should be able to take advantage of an index on `(message_id)`.

EDIT:

For the revised problem, I can't think right of hand of a really efficient method.  Here is one method:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where m.message_id in (select max(m2.message_id)
                       from messages m2
                       where :user in (sender_id, receiver_id)
                       group by (case when sender_id = :user then receiver_id else sender_id end)
                      );
```

Comment: This is nearly working, the problem is that I only get the last message of any chat. If you see in the example above I added another row, so that for 'sender_id' 20 I should get 2 rows: rows 2 and 4 (chat with user 100 and chat with user 57). But I get the last message that user 20 sent or received instead of getting last message of each different chat